Movie where the humans go to the alien homeworld to defeat them
I watched a movie some years ago. In the movie the human race faces a threat from aliens, and decide to go to the aliens' home world to destroy them once and forever.
This movie I am sure is a sequel or a part of movie series.

Were the aliens humanoid? Floating globs of energy? Lizard creatures? Had tentacles? About how many years ago was this? In the last 5 years? Two decades ago?

You can [edit] additional details in. As it is, this is kind of sparse.

Sounds like Ender's Game off the top of my head...

With the lack of detail this could just as easily be Battlefield Earth.

Or Starship Troopers.

Might this be the 2013 Ender's Game?

In the future, humanity is preparing to launch an attack on the homeworld of an alien race, called the Formics, that had attacked Earth and killed millions. The Formic invasion was stopped by Mazer Rackham, who crashed his fighter spaceship into the Formic queenship at the apparent cost of his life. Over the course of 50 years, gifted children are trained by the International Fleet to become commanders of a new fleet for this counterattack.

....

Ender's final test is monitored by several fleet commanders. As the simulation starts, Ender finds his fleet over the Formic homeworld, vastly outnumbered. He orders most of his fleet to sacrifice themselves to protect the MD long enough to fire on the homeworld. The resulting chain reaction burns the entire planet.

Trailer



